# How do I create a file from submitted raw base64 data?

Tags: php, drupal

I am trying to reconstruct a WAV/MP3 file from raw bases64 encoded data submitted in in a form. I understand th the steps should be something like:
1. Create new file
2. use file_put_content onto the new file with the decoded data
Is this correct? And what is the best/easiest way to do so?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? The easiest way is to use `file_put_contents()`, skipping the step 1

Comment: I actually used file put content and used unix sound libraries such as sox to manipulate the audio file.